# Wheel rotation, to change velocity of vehicle

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, objective-c

I update the velocity of my vehicle like so:

```
[v setVelocity:  ((2 * 3.14 * 100 * (wheel.getRotationValue / 360) / 30)) * gameSpeed]; // update on 60 fps this gets velocity on all frames divide by 60 for 1 frame.
```

This is done in my update method in my world class.

Now `wheel.getRotationValue` returns the rotation value which is worked out like this:

```
- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint(wheel.boundingBox, location))
    {
        CGPoint firstLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:[touch view]];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];

        CGPoint touchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
        CGPoint firstTouchingPoint = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:firstLocation];

        CGPoint firstVector = ccpSub(firstTouchingPoint, wheel.position);
        CGFloat firstRotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(firstVector);
        CGFloat previousTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(firstRotateAngle);

        CGPoint vector = ccpSub(touchingPoint, wheel.position);
        CGFloat rotateAngle = -ccpToAngle(vector);
        CGFloat currentTouch = CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(rotateAngle);

        float limit = 0.5;
        rotationValue += (currentTouch - previousTouch) * limit;
    }

    touching = YES;
}
```

Say I steer the vehicle to the far right of the screen, and want to move it to the far left, It wont start moving to the left of the screen until the rotationValue is past 0 degrees again (the wheel is in its center posistion) and is dragged past this value.

Is there anyway to change the code I have above, so that movement on the wheel is recognised instantly and updates the velocity of v instantly too?

Answer (score 3):

When you detect the absence of a touch (I'll leave that to you), reset your rotation value to 0.  Then any further change left will go left, etc.

If you want to do this when the user is continuously touching the interface, I think your question represents bad control design.  If the user, even for an instant, moves their finger in a direction away from the direction they are currently turning, they begin turning in the opposite direction?  That would be a horrible way to drive the car.  If you could somehow prevent it from being erratic (which I think you could not), it would still be highly counterintuitive.  Don't do that.